# SQL Server: How to DROP column constraints created by SSMA

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I have a medium-sized database (~230 table) that is getting migrated from Access 2010 to SQL Server 2008 R2, starting with an SSMA run.  There a bunch of nvarchar columns that SSMA is adding disallow_zero_length check constraint.  The nature of the data is that it is possible (and reasonable) for there to be zero-length values in these columns.  I'm new to SQL script (but learning as fast as I can) and I'm wondering how one would write a script that can iterate through the tables and drop the unwanted constraints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below query generates bunch of SQL drop statements. you can copy/paste the result into a SSMS window and execute it

```
select 'alter table ' + t.name + ' drop constraint ' + c.name
from sys.tables t
    inner join sys.check_constraints c on c.parent_object_id = t.object_id
where c.name like '%disallow_zero_length%'
```

Result is like this:

```
alter table t1 drop constraint disallow_zero_length_1
alter table t2 drop constraint disallow_zero_length_2
```

Just run the result statements.

<sub>Please Mark as Answer if this post answers your question.</sub>